# Asignar origen de datos a DataTable (JSON)

Tags: jquery

Tengo el siguiente array entregado por un json_encode de php:

```
[{"idproducto":"15","nombre":"IPA MOSAIC","unidad":"l","precio":"1.00","stock":"1.00","idcat":"1","idmarca":"1","codalfa":"ss","aliiva":"10.50","idsubcat":"1","granel":"1","contenido":"1.00","marca":"OTTRA","idcategoria":"1","detalle":"general","subcategoria":"general"},{"idproducto":"16","nombre":"GOLDEN ALE","unidad":"l","precio":"1.00","stock":"0.00","idcat":"1","idmarca":"1","codalfa":"tn","aliiva":"27.00","idsubcat":"1","granel":"1","contenido":"1.00","marca":"OTTRA","idcategoria":"1","detalle":"general","subcategoria":"general"},{"idproducto":"17","nombre":"PALE ALE","unidad":"l","precio":"1.00","stock":"0.00","idcat":"1","idmarca":"1","codalfa":"nt","aliiva":"21.00","idsubcat":"1","granel":"1","contenido":"1.00","marca":"OTTRA","idcategoria":"1","detalle":"general","subcategoria":"general"},{"idproducto":"18","nombre":"IRISH RED","unidad":"l","precio":"1.00","stock":"1.00","idcat":"1","idmarca":"1","codalfa":"nn","aliiva":"21.00","idsubcat":"1","granel":"1","contenido":"1.00","marca":"OTTRA","idcategoria":"1","detalle":"general","subcategoria":"general"},{"idproducto":"19","nombre":"DRY STOUT","unidad":"l","precio":"1.00","stock":"1.00","idcat":"1","idmarca":"1","codalfa":"nn","aliiva":"21.00","idsubcat":"1","granel":"1","contenido":"1.00","marca":"OTTRA","idcategoria":"1","detalle":"general","subcategoria":"general"},{"idproducto":"20","nombre":"KOLSH","unidad":"l","precio":"1.00","stock":"1.00","idcat":"1","idmarca":"1","codalfa":"nn","aliiva":"21.00","idsubcat":"1","granel":"1","contenido":"1.00","marca":"OTTRA","idcategoria":"1","detalle":"general","subcategoria":"general"},{"idproducto":"21","nombre":"HONEY","unidad":"l","precio":"1.00","stock":"1.00","idcat":"1","idmarca":"1","codalfa":"nn","aliiva":"21.00","idsubcat":"1","granel":"1","contenido":"1.00","marca":"OTTRA","idcategoria":"1","detalle":"general","subcategoria":"general"},{"idproducto":"22","nombre":"APA","unidad":"l","precio":"1.00","stock":"3.00","idcat":"1","idmarca":"1","codalfa":"nn","aliiva":"21.00","idsubcat":"1","granel":"1","contenido":"1.00","marca":"OTTRA","idcategoria":"1","detalle":"general","subcategoria":"general"},{"idproducto":"24","nombre":"COCA COLA 500","unidad":"l","precio":"20.00","stock":"-1788.00","idcat":"1","idmarca":"1","codalfa":"nn","aliiva":"21.00","idsubcat":"1","granel":"2","contenido":"500.00","marca":"OTTRA","idcategoria":"1","detalle":"general","subcategoria":"general"},{"idproducto":"25","nombre":"DORADA PAMPEANA","unidad":"l","precio":"50.00","stock":"1.00","idcat":"1","idmarca":"1","codalfa":"nn","aliiva":"21.00","idsubcat":"1","granel":"1","contenido":"0.00","marca":"OTTRA","idcategoria":"1","detalle":"general","subcategoria":"general"},{"idproducto":"26","nombre":"PORTER","unidad":"l","precio":"0.00","stock":"1.00","idcat":"2","idmarca":"1","codalfa":"nn","aliiva":"21.00","idsubcat":"1","granel":"1","contenido":"0.00","marca":"OTTRA","idcategoria":"1","detalle":"construccion en seco","subcategoria":"general"},{"idproducto":"28","nombre":"BOCONA","unidad":"L","precio":"130.00","stock":"-362.38","idcat":"1","idmarca":"1","codalfa":"NN","aliiva":"21.00","idsubcat":"1","granel":"2","contenido":"0.00","marca":"OTTRA","idcategoria":"1","detalle":"general","subcategoria":"general"},{"idproducto":"29","nombre":"BOCONA","unidad":"l","precio":"120.00","stock":"0.00","idcat":"1","idmarca":"1","codalfa":"nn","aliiva":"21.00","idsubcat":"1","granel":"2","contenido":"120.00","marca":"OTTRA","idcategoria":"1","detalle":"general","subcategoria":"general"},{"idproducto":"30","nombre":"BOCONA","unidad":"l","precio":"33.00","stock":"0.00","idcat":"1","idmarca":"1","codalfa":"nn","aliiva":"21.00","idsubcat":"1","granel":"2","contenido":"22.00","marca":"OTTRA","idcategoria":"1","detalle":"general","subcategoria":"general"}]
```

Y bueno estoy leyendo la documentacion de datatable que es esta: [MANUAL](https://datatables.net/manual/),

Pero hice una funcion que obtiene el array en JQuery y tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
var arrayArticulos = null;
$(document).ready(function(){



dameArticulos();

 $('#articulos').DataTable({

data:arrayArticulos,
    columns: [
        { title: "Name" },
        { title: "Position" },
        { title: "Office" },
        { title: "Extn." },
        { title: "Start date" },
        { title: "Salary" }
    ],
aoColumns: [
        { "mData": "idproducto" },

    ],
language:{
                    "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
                    "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                    "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",
                    "sEmptyTable":     "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
                    "sInfo":           "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
                    "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
                    "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                    "sInfoPostFix":    "",
                    "sSearch":         "Buscar:",
                    "sUrl":            "",
                    "sInfoThousands":  ",",
                    "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                    "oPaginate": {
                        "sFirst":    "Primero",
                        "sLast":     "Último",
                        "sNext":     "Siguiente",
                        "sPrevious": "Anterior"
                    },
                    "oAria": {
                        "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                        "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
                    }
                    },
      responsive: true });

});
function dameArticulos(){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../gestionn/views/modules/articulo/procesoarticulo.php",
    data: { "accion":"listar"}, 
    dataType:"json",

    error: function(){
        alert("error petición ajax");
        arrayArticulos  = null;
    },
    success:function(data){
        arrayArticulos  = data;
    },
});
};
```

Como veran probe pasar el array a "data", pero no me muestra los datos.
Puede ser que falte asociar la columna al campo del array? De ser que si como lo hago?

Bueno, descubri que la variable del arrayArticulos se cargar dentro del success pero no llega al ambito de la dataTable, que debo hacer? Manejar todo dentro del success, o como puedo manejar una variable global con el JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Lo publico como respuesta porque logre armar la tabla:

```js
function dameArticulos(){
  
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../gestionn/views/modules/articulo/procesoarticulo.php",
        data: { "accion":"listar"}, 
        dataType:"json",

        error: function(){
            alert("error petición ajax");
            arrayArticulos  = null;
        },
        success:function(data){
        arrayArticulos=data;
         $('#articulos').DataTable({

    data:arrayArticulos,
                columnDefs: [
                { type: "num", symbols:"$" , targets: 5 }
            ],
 
        columns: [
        {data:"codalfa", title: "COD.:" },
        {"data": "nombre", title: "NOMBRE" },
        {"data": "marca", title: "MARCA" },
        {"data": "precio",  "title": "P/U" },
        {"data": "detalle", title: "CAT.:" },
        {"data": "subcategoria", title: "SUBCAT.:" }
    ], 
 
  
  
    language:{
                        "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
                        "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                        "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",
                        "sEmptyTable":     "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
                        "sInfo":           "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
                        "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
                        "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                        "sInfoPostFix":    "",
                        "sSearch":         "Buscar:",
                        "sUrl":            "",
                        "sInfoThousands":  ",",
                        "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                        "oPaginate": {
                            "sFirst":    "Primero",
                            "sLast":     "Último",
                            "sNext":     "Siguiente",
                            "sPrevious": "Anterior"
                        },
                        "oAria": {
                            "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                            "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
                        }
                        },
          responsive: true });

        },
    });
};
```

Es decir, funciono dentro del success.